# Timer.schedule runs once even with period

Tags: java, android, timertask

I'm a student trying to create an app for my miniproject for one of my modules and I'm trying to create an app that grabs data from a server every few seconds so it's **updated**. I tried using java timer and timerTask to run the code repeatedly but the program only run once and the get-button doesn't work as intended (suppose to grab data instantly) after implementing the timer. [Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WkAg.png)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener{

private Button speed;
private TextView result;
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
private TextView sSpeed;
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    sSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sSpeed);
    speed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_button);
    speed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           getWebsite();
       }
    });
    View aboutButton = this.findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View exitButton = this.findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.get_button:
            getWebsite();
            break;
        case R.id.about_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.exit_button:
            finish();
            break;
    }
}

private void getWebsite(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {


            try{
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://10.0.2.2:8080/Start_Stop_buttons_UTF8.html").get();
               // Elements element = doc.getElementsByTag("p");
                Elements element = doc.select("p");
                //String title = doc.title();
                builder.append(title).append("\n");
                for (Element tag : element){
                    builder.append("\n\n").append(tag.text());
                }

            }catch(IOException e){
                //e.printStackTrace();
                builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String a = builder.toString(); // parse data from html into new string
                    a = a.substring(a.indexOf(":")+1, a.indexOf("Control")).trim();//trim string content
                    String b = builder.toString();
                    b = b.substring(11,b.indexOf(":")+1).trim();
                
                    double speed = Double.parseDouble(a);//convert string into double
                    if (speed<1000)
                        Log.i("HTML text","too slow");
                    else if((speed> 1500))Log.i("HTML text","too fast!");

                    result.setText(a);
                    sSpeed.setText(b);
                }
            });
        }

    }).start();

}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    startTimer();
}

public void startTimer(){
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getWebsite();

        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask,1500,3000);
}

public void stopTimer(){
    if(timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }
}
```

}

Am I implementing the timer correctly to run getwebsite() repeatedly and able to get an instant update when get-button is clicked like it should have? Or is there a better way to implement these features using different method?

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling the `startTimer` method in your `ClickListener`. You make one call to `getWebsite`. Change your call to `startTimer`.

```
 speed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           startTimer();
       }
    });
```

You also might want to check if the timer is already running before you start a new one. To do that assign a `null` value on your `stopTimer` method e.g.

```
public void stopTimer(){
    if(timer != null){
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

And your `startTimer` would look like this

```
public void startTimer(){
    if(timer != null) return; // don't start multiple timers
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getWebsite();

        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask,1500,3000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer might prove useful but I'm still getting the same errors: it's still not updating to changes in the data displayed. I tried changing the intended data to be displayed on the web but it's not showing in the emulator. Does the problem lies with the timer or is it my codes?

Comment: Also, what's the reason the "get-button" is not responding from my codes?